# Centos 7 , WHM High Mysql&MariaDB CPU Usage %600

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem.
My web site very slowly
I think it's mysql.
Max user connection instant 100 users.
30-40 people in most cases.

My server :

- Intel Xeon E3-1230v3
- 16 GB DDR3 Ram
- 240 GB OCZ SSD Disk
- Centos 7 WHM-cPanel MariaDB

...

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
12496 mysql   20   0   14.1g   1.3g  12228 S 576.1  8.2 116:38.62
```

/usr/sbin/mysqld

/etc/my.cnf :

```
port        = 1905
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# The MySQL Safe server
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 58000
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
max_connections = 300
local-infile    = 0
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 1024M
table_open_cache = 4096
open_files_limit = 40960
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
join_buffer_size = 4M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
thread_cache_size = 16
#query_cache_size= 32M
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M

#table_cache    = 1024

#Slowly log
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_file_per_table= 1
#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:50M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8096M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 64M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 64M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

# Connection Settings
wait_timeout = 60
skip-external-locking



[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 64M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M
# Query Cache Settings
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 256K
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 80M
skip-external-locking

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

How Can I do this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: High CPU almost always comes from slow queries.  Since you already have the slowlog turned on, please [_digest it and show us what you find_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog).  _Then_ we should be able to quickly help you.  (Wilson's requested `SHOWs` _may_ be useful, too.)

Comment: 8.3% Memory does not make sense; please check.

Comment: I put in pastebin, link : https://pastebin.com/6ACte0ib

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks, I've prepared their last wishes, they're here: https://pastebin.com/M6c8LetR Sorry, I'm not usage Skype :(

Comment: @RickJames What do you think of all this? I have uploaded all request to pastebin..

Comment: @Aras - Something went wrong in pasting the `VARIABLES`; the first half of them are missing.@Aras

Comment: @WilsonHauck - _This_ time, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` (or a digested slowlog) was all that was needed.  And, again, "you can't tune your way out of a performance problem."

Comment: @aras Need your help, please.  Furkan, the MONTHLY part of your calculations would be wrong.  It is 3 times a year.  Since the client has not been in touch with me, to acknowledge who he WANTS the participants to be and your person at the site does not know how to add an INDEX and you can not add the indexes requested by Rick James, can aras at StackOverflow guide us on the next step he wants to see accomplished before we are looking at SLOW time again all day on Monday for ALL of his clients?

Comment: @aras Not heard back from you or Furkan in the past week.  Guessing the problem went away or more important issues are taking your time.  Please let us know if you are OK or need assistance.  Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1):

**Bottom line:**  Adding a few indexes will help a lot:

```
INDEX(islemkey)
INDEX(site, durum, islem_baslangic)
INDEX(durum, site, site_durum, id)
```

**Details**

```
UPDATE odemeler SET step='odeme_kontrol' WHERE islemkey = '78TNgyacgjwt'
```

You need `INDEX(islemkey)` on `odemeler`.

```
`expire` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
AND islem_baslangic LIKE '2018-11-29%'
```

If `expire` is a `DATE` or `DATETIME`, then it should be declared such.  If it is in some non-standard date format, then it needs converting.  Ditto for `islem_baslangic` and any other columns that contain dates.

```
SELECT * FROM odemeler WHERE site = '71' AND durum = '1'
```

`odemeler` needs this composite `INDEX(site, durum)`; optionally they could be listed in the opposite order.

```
SELECT id,tcno, miktar,durum,islem_baslangic,site,site_durum
    FROM odemeler
    WHERE site = '74' AND durum = '1' AND site_durum = '0'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Needs

```
INDEX(site, durum, site_durum,  -- in any order
      id)   -- last
```

**Reason**

Without a usable index, most of the queries showing in the `PROCESSLIST` must scan the entire table.  This takes a lot of CPU.  And it slows down each query.  And then the queries stack up.  (That was a lot of queries to have in the `PROCESSLIST` at once.)

With usable indexes, each query will come and go much faster and use much less CPU.  That's the purpose of indexes!

Answer (score 0):

Login to the WHM with root user , From Multi PHP manager , switch the website to PHP 7.1 
enable php-fpm for that particular website.

Secondly , download the mysql tuner script which will help you to tweak /etc/my.cnf settings for the best mysql performance.

if the things are not working even after all these changes then you will have to optimize your mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS  Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section for performance improvement,

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from 128M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS from 6 million +
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to enable more of your SSD io capacity
thread_cache_size=100  # from 16 to reduce threads_created count of 24,136 in 8 hrs
aria_pagecache_buffer_size=64M  # from 128M to conserve RAM, only 2 blocks used in 8 hrs
key_buffer_size=128M  # from 1G to conserve RAM, 15M used was the High Water Mark
```

Aras and Furkan, If you still do not have your indexes created, suggested by Rick James, please post a comment indicating you need help with this request to improve performance by index management.

Comment: @aras A) Have the above suggestions been implemented? B) response time better or worse?